# JFace table deactivate cells for certain rows

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

Is there a ways to enable/disable cells in a JFace TableViewer?
I have a combobox and based on the data set in that box the user should either be able to changed the data in a certain cell or not.
There is a TextCellEditor for each column, that needs to be enabled/disabled.

I can't think of any good way to achieve that, maybe you do?

Comment: If you are using `EditingSupport` you have the `canEdit` method.

Comment: is there a way to grey out the specific cell if I disable it in the canEdit method

Comment: If you are using a label provider based on `ColumnLabelProvider` override the `getBackground` / `getForeground` methods.

Comment: greg, I don't think you know how much ur help is appreciated. Thanks a lot. Your fast responses keep my project alive :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using an `EditingSupport` class for the editing your implementation of the `canEdit` method determines if the cell can be edited.

If you are using column label providers based on `ColumnLabelProvider` you can override the `getForeground` and `getBackground` methods to set cell colors appropriately.

You may need to call one of the table viewer `refresh` or `update` methods if you want to change the edit state or cell color.